# How do I include a file in a class?

Tags: php

I want to include a file to be accessible to any method/function in a PHP class. The file just contains a base-64 encoded variable. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: "The file just contains a base-64 encoded variable" - as php code like `<?php $i = '...';` ?

Comment: Do you have control over this file, i.e. a) is it trustworthy b) can you change the format ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this situation, you'd better use a constant.

```
define('MY_BASE64_VAR', base64_encode('foo'));
```

It will be available everywhere and immutable.

```
require "constant.php";
class Bar {
    function showVariable() {echo MY_BASE64_VAR;}
}
```

Of course, you will still need to include the file where it is defined prior to using it in you classes.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php include("common.php"); ?>
```

Check [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/include.php).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make sure that it is included in every class, make sure you include it in every class but use the include_once for efficency

```
<?php include_once("common.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just save the base64 encoded data, without any additional php code in that file you can simply read its contents, decode the data and assign it to a property of the object.

```
class Foo {
  protected $x;

  public function setSource($path) {
    // todo: add as much validating/sanitizing code as needed
    $c = file_get_contents($path);
    $this->x = base64_decode($c);
  }

  public function bar() {
    echo 'x=', $this->x;
  }
}

// this will create/overwrite the file test.stackoverflow.txt, which isn't removed at the end of the script.
file_put_contents('test.stackoverflow.txt', base64_encode('mary had a little lamb'));
$foo = new Foo;
$foo->setSource('test.stackoverflow.txt');
$foo->bar();
```

prints `x=mary had a little lamb`.

(You might want to decouple that a bit more ...but it's only an example.)